# Get Emails from Gmail using Google App Script as 10 mins before to current time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, gmail

I want to search email using Google App Script as 10 mins before to current time, I wrote the below script but it's not working, as I have emails with the same subject as defined in query and before 10 mins(even 1 min before mails are there) but GAS showing zero threads.

```js
function testforemails(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var Gmail = GmailApp;
  var lasttime = sheet.getRange("Z1").getValue(); // it will use later as the time of last searched email.
  Logger.log(lasttime);
  var cdate = new Date();
  var ctime = cdate.getTime();
  var qDate = new Date(ctime - 600000); // less 10 minutes from current time.
  Utilities.formatDate(qDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm a")
  Logger.log("QDATE IS " + qDate); //  perfectly displaying time less than 10 minutes
  var qtime = qDate.getTime();
  Logger.log("qtime is " + qtime);

  // SEARCH EMAIL
  var query = 'subject: defined subject of emails, after:' + (qDate);
  var threadsNew = Gmail.search(query);
  Logger.log(threadsNew.length);
  var folderid = 'define folder id'
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
  for(var n in threadsNew){
    var thdNew  = threadsNew[n]; 
    var msgsNew = thdNew.getMessages();　
    var msgNew = msgsNew[msgsNew.length-1];
  // GET ATTACHMENT
    var bodyNew = msgNew.getBody();
    var plainbody  = msgNew.getPlainBody();
    var subject = msgNew.getSubject();
    var Etime = msgNew.getDate();
    var attachments = msgNew.getAttachments();
    var attachment = attachments[0];
    
    Logger.log(Etime);
    Logger.log(subject);
  }
    
    Logger.log(threadsNew.length);
    
    
}
```

Comment: From Gmail UI search box it seems that search by date is optional only in a day resolution (range of dates, without hours / minutes). Are you sure that possible from script?

Comment: @Elchanan shuky Shukrun: yeah, that's why I'm looking for the solution because I want to save the time of the last scan and search after the last scan time. So is it possible? any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

In Gmail search operators, `before` and `after` timestamps work with seconds, not with milliseconds.

#### Solution:

Divide the timestamp by 1000, making sure it's an integer:

```
function testforemails(){
  var cdate = new Date();
  var ctime = cdate.getTime();
  var qDate = new Date(ctime - 600000); // less 10 minutes from current time.
  var query = 'after:' + Math.floor(qDate.getTime()/1000);
  var threadsNew = GmailApp.search(query);
  Logger.log(threadsNew.length);
  // ...
}
```

#### Other issues:

- In your query you provided the date directly, without transforming to the number of milliseconds. This cannot work:

```
var qDate = new Date(ctime - 600000);
var query = 'subject: defined subject of emails, after:' + (qDate);
```

#### Related:

- [Is it possible to query Gmail messages by timestamp?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67766/is-it-possible-to-query-gmail-messages-by-timestamp)

Comment: Thanks, regarding the other issues. point 1 is I already defined Gmail as GmailApp above so it's correct. and 2nd issue you highlighted is correct.

Comment: @MehdiAbbas Oh sure yeah I missed that about `GmailApp`. Also, please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

This is accualy can be done, see the asnwer of @Iamblichus. Anyway, my method also works so I keep for the user to choose which method better for his needs.

---

A workaround to achive this goal:

```
function testforemails(){
  // SEARCH EMAIL
  let now = new Date();
  let query = 'subject: YOUR_SUBJECT, after:' + now.toISOString().slice(0, 10); // find mails from today
  console.log(query);
  let threadsNew = GmailApp.search(query);
  console.log("threadsNew.length: " + threadsNew.length);

  for(let thread of threadsNew){
    let lastMsgTime = thread.getLastMessageDate();
    let tenMinutesAgo = new Date(now - 600000);

    if(lastMsgTime - tenMinutesAgo > 0) { // if the last message on the thread was less than 10 minutes ago
      // do your magic here
      console.log(thread.getLastMessageDate())
    }  
  }    
}
```

Comment: thank you very much as after your first comment I was thinking the same idea during prayers and you do it, Superb.

Comment: in this case, both answers are correct. but @Elchanan shuky Shukrun is first mover.

Comment: While the workaround is valid, people reading this answer might get the impression that this cannot be done with search operators directly, which is not true.

Comment: @Iamblichus added ref to your answer, I didn't know the seconds / milliseconds issue, so thank you!